# cascading the drop-down using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to cascade my drop-down box with another drop-down.So that second drop-down will list options related to the item selected in the first drop-down box.I have tried a sample code , and drop-down still remains empty.

html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Car Type">
  <ion-content ng-app="CarWash" ng-contorller="carBrand">
   <h3> Add/Edit the Car Types </h3>
   Make:
        <select id="brand" ng-model="carBrand" ng-options="brand for (brand,item) in brandList">
          <option value=''>Select</option> 
        </select>

Type:
<select id="makeType" ng-model="brandType" ng-options="item for (brand,item) in brandlist">
  <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller:

```
[angular.module('CarWash',\[\]).controller('carBrand',\['$scope',function($scope){

  $scope.brandList={'Benz':\['Regular','Truck'\]};
}\])]
```

link[1](https://plnkr.co/edit/LB8oAz8PK7cdsC6CII20)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
<select name="client" ng-model="selectedRequest.parentType" ng-options="c.name.en for c in clients.brandList" required></select>
<select id="department" ng-model="selectedRequest.subType" ng-options="d.name.en for d in  selectedRequest.parentType.children">
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/5z485cq1/7/)**

Comment: And other query will I be able to do add and delete function using this.

Comment: I tried this logic in ionic but it doesn't give any output, the drop down still remains blank.. @Sajeetharan

Comment: @sree check your json

Comment: Since Im new to ionic and angularjs can you explain me why to check json file... sorry @Sajeetharan

Comment: because that is where data is loaded from, can you create a sample and show i willl find out the issue

Comment: {
"carbrand":{"bmw":{"carname":["suv","sedan","cope"]},"mercedes":{"carname":["sedan","cope"]}}
}